# Particionado de tablas y grupos de archivos

Tags: sql-server

He estado buscando en internet y en este foro temas sobre el particionado de tablas y por lo que he visto en la mayoría de ejemplos se crean los grupos de archivos en unidades de disco que al parecer son diferentes de en donde está el `.mdf`; no se es muy explícito con respecto a esto.

Tengo entonces dos preguntas:

- ¿tiene sentido o mejora el rendimiento crear los grupos de archivos para particionar tablas en la misma unidad HDD ?
- si vale la pena ¿ se optimiza también el uso de los datos con solo crear mas de un grupo de archivo además del primario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El particionado de tablas en SQL Server no es una herramienta para mejorar el rendimiento del sistema. En algunos casos puede, inclusive, degradar el rendimiento al tener que hacer búsquedas en múltiples árboles de índices.

Particionar las tablas es una herramienta para facilitar y agilizar la administración del almacenamiento de la base de datos. De esa forma se puede pasar información histórica de manera rápida a un archivo de solo lectura o en un disco con menor rendimiento pero mayor espacio. También permite hacer respaldos parciales por grupo de archivos en bases de datos de gran tamaño.

Respecto a crear los grupos de archivos en la misma unidad HDD, no tiene sentido porque sería fragmentar automáticamente los índices por diseño. Es decir, estás indicando que los datos de una tabla estén en varios puntos del disco en vez de estar en los mismos sectores.

Se debe tener mucho cuidado al particionar tablas, ya que puede generar muchos problemas. Es importante que se reduzca la mínimo la información recabada de múltiples particiones en una sola consulta y eso requiere que siempre se use la columna de partición como filtro.